# Jquery: does not replace the Dropdown first value with new selected one

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put 2 dropdown so that one the user selects on the given value the dropdown change automatically.
I have done something like this:

```
 <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle searchcmp1" data-toggle="dropdown"><span id="#search-replace1">Filtrer par</span><span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul id="bnq1" class="dropdown-menu">
              <?php
                $rows=MainController:: getBanque();
               while ($row =$rows->fetch())
                  echo '<li><a>'.$row['abrvb'].'</a></li>';
              ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle searchcmp2" data-toggle="dropdown"><span id="#search-replace2">Filtrer par</span><span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul id="bnq2" class="dropdown-menu">
              <?php
                $rows=MainController:: getBanque();
               while ($row =$rows->fetch())
                  echo '<li><a>'.$row['abrvb'].'</a></li>';
              ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      <input type="button" id="cmpBtn" class="filter btn btn-info" name="filter" value="Filtrer">
    </div>
```

And here is my Jquery code to modify the appropriate span with the newest selected value:

```
 $("ul#bnq1 li a").click(function(){
    alert("ok1")
  var selHtml = $(this).html();
  var selName = $.trim($(this).text());
  $(this).parents('.input-group').find('#search-replace1').html(selHtml);
  //$(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.searchcmp1').val(selName);
});
$("ul#bnq2 li a").click(function(){
  alert("ok2")
var selHtml = $(this).html();
var selName = $.trim($(this).text())
$(this).parents('.btn-group').find('#search-replace2').html(selHtml);
$(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.searchcmp2').val(selName);
});
```

The problem is that the selected value has not been affected to the span even though it got it correctly.
What is the problem how could I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in specifying the `id` in this line `<span id="#search-replace1">Filtrer par</span>`. You should not use the `#` symbol in the `id` attribute in the html element. The `#` symbol is used in the jquery selector to identify that the text that follows is an `id`.

See the corrected code below.

```js
$("ul#bnq1 li a").click(function() {
  alert("ok1")
  var selHtml = $(this).html();
  var selName = $.trim($(this).text());
  $(this).parents('.input-group').find('#search-replace1').html(selHtml);
  //$(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.searchcmp1').val(selName);
});
$("ul#bnq2 li a").click(function() {
  alert("ok2")
  var selHtml = $(this).html();
  var selName = $.trim($(this).text())
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('#search-replace2').html(selHtml);
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.searchcmp2').val(selName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle searchcmp1" data-toggle="dropdown"><span id="search-replace1">Filtrer par</span><span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul id="bnq1" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a>one</a></li>
        <li><a>two</a></li>
        <li><a>three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle searchcmp2" data-toggle="dropdown"><span id="search-replace2">Filtrer par</span><span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul id="bnq2" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a>one</a></li>
        <li><a>two</a></li>
        <li><a>three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="cmpBtn" class="filter btn btn-info" name="filter" value="Filtrer">
</div>
```